# Density of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$. Constructive Proof.

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers, constructive-mathematics

Is there any constructive proof that between two real numbers there is a rational number (I don't think so, but I don't really know)?

Comment: What is your brand of constructive mathematics? How do you define real numbers in that?

Comment: Now that I think so (And as I thought a few hours ago), it seems very hard to answer that. But I got carried away, I just wanted to know if there is a proof of this without relying in the archimedean property or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. First prove that for each $x\in\mathbb R$ there is some $n\in\mathbb Z$ such that $n\leq x<n+1$ (for this, consider cases for $x$ and use the well ordering principle and the archimedean property). Such $n$ is usually denoted by $\lfloor x\rfloor.$ Next, proceed as follows.

Let $x,y\in\mathbb R$ be such that $y<x.$ By the archimedean property, there is some $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $1<n(x-y)\iff ny+1<nx.$ Now let $m:=\lfloor ny\rfloor.$ Then $ny<m+1\leq ny+1$ and it follows that $ny<m+1<nx$ and hence $y<\dfrac{m+1}{n}<x.$

Comment: When we use the archimedean property, is there any way we can "find the $n$", in this case?

Comment: @LeviathanTheEsper I'm not sure what you mean. What I did was to use the fact that $x-y>0$ (because $x>y$), which implies that $1/(x-y)>0.$ Then, by the archimedean property, there exists $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $n>1/(x-y)\iff n(x-y)>1.$ If you want to explicitly find such $n,$ well it would be a bit hard (although you can let $n:=\lfloor 1/(x-y)\rfloor+1$).

Comment: Yes, I mean that. Find explicitly the $n$ in both cases, even when we want to prove that for each $x\in\mathbb R$ there is some $n\in\mathbb Z$ such that $n\leq x<n+1$, but I think it's asking a lot (And that if it's possible, finding that $n$ would be very hard).

Or more exactly, is there any constructive proof of the Archimedean property?

Comment: I don't know if there is such a proof